# Is a formatted string still a string? Is it still printable, or it is just a bunch of rules?

Tags: java, java-stream, string-formatting

I am looking at other code on a Java practice. Here is his code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StripComments {

    public static String stripComments(String text, String[] commentSymbols) {
        String pattern = String.format(
                "[ ]*([%s].*)?$",
                Arrays.stream( commentSymbols ).collect( Collectors.joining() )
        );
        return Arrays.stream( text.split( "\n" ) )
                .map( x -> x.replaceAll( pattern, "" ) )
                .collect( Collectors.joining( "\n" ) );
    }

}
```

In his code, the pattern is representing something after whatever in the commentSymbols, right? If I decide to print the pattern right after the string creation, what would the pattern be like? If pattern is a printable string, why in the later sentence we can use it to filter out the sentence we want to delete?

I used debug mode and it showed pattern looks like this `"[ ]*([#!].*)?$"` while the inputs are `("apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples", new String[]{"#", "!"})`. Does this string have any meaning? If I just initialize a new string and assign this value `"[ ]*([#!].*)?$"` to it, would it work same?

Comment: The meaning of a string is determined by the way you use it. In this specific example, the string is passed as first argument to [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) which expects a regex pattern string. But note that this entire method can be shorted to `return text.replaceAll("(?m) *([" + String.join("", commentSymbols) + "].*)?$", "");` which does not use the `format` method, showing that this method is not relevant here (and probably the most abused method ever).

Answer (score 4):

It helps to break down the steps in the code.  There is a lot in that example packed into a small space.

The `x -> x.replaceAll( pattern, "" )` expression is calling the `replaceAll` method on a string named `x`.  If you look at that method definition, you will see how the regular expression, `[ ]*([#!].*)?$`, is used.  Yes, that regular expression is being passed in as a String.

And, yes, if you hard-code the same string and pass it to `replaceAll` it will produce the same result.

The `Arrays.stream()` call is using minimal syntax to iterate over the elements of the array `commentSymbols`.  If you look up the `Collectors.joining()` method call, you will find that concatenates all of the strings it is fed.  So if you input 2 strings, `"a"` and `"b"`, it will end up producing a single String, `"ab"`.

Then the return value of `Arrays.stream()` is passed to `String.format` where the `%s` in the first, format, argument is replaced with that value.

Comment: BTW, I recommend making a small `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` program with the code and try it out.  Start with small parts of the code and see what they are doing.

Comment: Also note that one could replace `Arrays.stream( commentSymbols ).collect( Collectors.joining() )` with the shorter and simpler `String.join("", commentSymbols)`

Comment: @ThomasKläger the entire method can be shortened to `return text.replaceAll("(?m) *([" + String.join("", commentSymbols) + "].*)?$", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two patterns you provided are functionally equivalent. Both patterns, `[ ]*([%s].*)?$ and [ ]*([#!].*)?$`, serve the same purpose in the context of the stripComments method. They are designed to match and remove any characters following the specified comment symbols (`#` and `!` in this case) until the end of the line.

The `%s` in the first pattern is a placeholder for the characters in the commentSymbols array, and when you substitute it with actual values using String.format, it becomes `[ ]*([#!].*)?$`, which is the same as the second pattern.

So, both patterns are equivalent and will produce the same result when used in the `stripComments` method for the given input.